# What happens when int is inside round bracket?

Tags: java, syntax

I know the code below return the ASCII value for 'A', but I don't understand what (int) do.

System.out.print((int) 'A');

Output: 65

Comment: Sounds like you need a very basic Java tutorial. Please research "casting" in Java, specifically with regards to integer types.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `(int)` there is a [cast](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.4). 
You're casting the `char` literal `A` to an `int`, thus widening a two-byte representation of 65 to a four-byte representation.

Answer (score 2):

its Just casting your char as an int.

```
char character = 'a';    
int ascii = (int) character;
```

Comment: ["Character literals can only represent UTF-16 code units."](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.10.4). UTF-16 is one of the character encodings for the [Unicode](http://www.unicode.org/charts/nameslist/index.html) character set. Any similarity with another character set, such as ASCII, is irrelevant.

Answer (score 2):

When you use 'A' inside the sysout. Your just printing it as is. But when used with any inside () you will be casting as said above. You may try these.

```
System.out.println((Character)'A'); --> Prints A
   System.out.println((Object)'A'); --> Prints A
   System.out.println((float)'A'); --> 65.0
   System.out.println((byte)'A'); --> 65
```

As a matter of proof.

```
System.out.println((Integer)'A'); --> Cannot cast from char to Integer
  System.out.println((Float)'A'); --> Cannot cast from char to Float
```